# Suggestions on how to build a breadcrumb trail for dynamic content in a CMS

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I have a URL naming convention for various parts of a CMS we built, and want to build a breadcrumb trail as you move through it. The problem I'm having is that you can't simply replace the parts of the URL path with back links (and capitalized words); each part of the URL path tells the CMS what actions to perform. I'm going to do my best to illustrate in this space:

The URL:

```
/news/list/item/1
```

would create the breadcrumb:

```
Home > News > General News (category ID=1)
```

and list the news posts where `categoryID=1`.

But at the same time the URL:

```
/news/add/category
```

would create the breadcrumb:

```
Home > News > Add Category
```

And the URL:

```
/news/edit/item/25 (let's assume post 25 is in category 1)
```

would create the breadcrumb:

```
Home > News > General News > Edit Post (post ID=25)
```

and display the `postID=25` for editing

So you hopefully can see where I'm getting tripped up; "list" "edit" and "add" are basically the three things you can do as you're moving through the CMS (delete's done a little differently in case anyone's curious why I left that off), but the breadcrumbs don't match the URL level-for-level. Thus, it isn't a matter of simply parsing the URL path into an array and creating the breadcrumb based on the various parts.

I hope I was able to explain this well enough...this isn't so much a coding question (although any sample code would be appreciated), rather a question about structure and strategy on how to approach this. Also, it's worth noting that the "news" part of the URL will change to other modules that are installed in the CMS, each having a separate Module.class.php file where all their functions are stored.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could have read this without that edit, Paul. ¬_¬

Comment: sorry about that, or I suppose you'd prefer Sorry about that. Thank you, Jared, for cleaning up my markup...I apologize for confusing the code and narrative

Comment: Is your action always the second token in the list?

Comment: yes. it goes module/action/type/item (type pretty much says which table to look into. Item is typically the WHERE clause)

Comment: Also, this is why in frameworks like CodeIgniter you typically have the MVC path put the action last (or at least third) for your class loader, and have a default view for index. This would mean your controller would interprete `/news/item/add` and `/new/category/edit` instead of `news/add/item` or `/news/edit/category`. This would make your view syntax match evenly with the edit and add syntax, and your path is predicated on subject and not on objective.

Comment: I started that way, but decided to switch it so I could follow my code more easily (I group all my add_X, edit_X functions together)

Comment: You might want to create a Breadcrumbs class that takes a path, puts it through a switch case to determine the variations and the output required, and establish the view text for each part. This way, you would control the edit and add (and presumably delete) paths independently but have only one place to edit when you need to update that logic.

Answer (score 3):

You have not shared much about the design of your CMS, e.g. how you structure the requests into modules and actions. However as long as a breadcrumb is what you ask for, those normally are just a list of links.

If you encapsulate a list (array) into a class, you can instantiate the breadcrumb with the request and than make various parts of your application add the breadcrumbs they need to add to it.

The frontend controller could add the home link (`Home`). The module can add the module link for the index action (`News`), the specific action can then add the last links as it suits (`General News`).

They all just share the breadcrumb object with the request and job done.

That's for a MVC type application, I think it's easily to adopt for any sort of design.

```
class BreadcrumbTrail
{
    private $breadcrumbs = array();
    public function add($label, $link)
    {
        $this->breadcrumbs[] = array($label, $link);
    }
    public function toArray()
    {
        return $this->breadcrumbs;
    }
}


$breadcrumbs = new BreadcrumbTrail();
$breadcrumbs->add('Home', '/');
```

Inject the breadcrumb then as a dependency or use some context to provide it to the different modules / controllers you have.

The more your application grows or the more features you need, you can extend this structure (e.g interfaces, a concrete class for the breadcrumb itself etc.), this is just for demonstrating the basic idea.

Comment: That's not a bad approach; only thing I'd probably consider is changing to static methods.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: What would be the benefit of static methods? That you can only use one breadcrumb trail? Then you should use a global variable instead.

Comment: I would prefer a static method or process to a global variable. Since ultimately what is needed is a way to turn a path into an English-readable text, registering a path part's meaning is what the class is for (IMO). A static process could accommodate multiple breadcrumb sets, as well. Like I said though, I would consider it; I'm not saying it's the best way in all cases.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: The class is only representing the trail and nothing more. I think a static method would be in the domain of dealing with instance(s), so I would not put that into the trail but somewhere else. But concrete implementations can always differ, I don't know as well how the design of the application is. However statics often degrade usability.

Comment: Interesting idea; since each of the type/action combinations have a separate master template file (for display purposes; some have multiple tables, tabbed "widgets", etc) I could call each part of the breadcrumb separately. Wouldn't be totally efficient, but might get me past the problem of matching up my URL to the actions, etc. that Jared pointed out initially. Thanks to both of you.